# XSLT, grab just a portion of a string within a tag

Tags: xml, xslt

alright, i have an xslt stylesheet that does most of what i need now, it looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="//Product/Description">
    <title>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </title>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//Product/Picture">
    <link>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </link>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//Product/Caption">
    <description>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </description>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Picture">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, 'src=')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Caption">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&gt;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is probably a huge kludge because i am just grabbing the text from the 'raw' output of my xml editor because it does what i need.  it is putting the correct tags in the right places.  however, now the 'strip-tag' doesnt seem to work, and i tried to make another version of the 'strip-tag' that would strip everything following 'src=' and preceding '>' but obviously 'strip-tag' would be the opposite of what i am trying to do. is there something that does the opposite of 'strip-tag'? then i could just replace the word 'strip-tag' with 'strip-all-except' or whatever it would be called

EDIT:
here is the input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE StoreExport SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/StoreExport.dtd">
<StoreExport>
  <Settings>
    <Published timestamp="1297187196"/>
    <Locale code="C" name="English" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
    <StoreName>Cl33333</StoreName>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <ShipMethods>
      <ShipMethod></ShipMethod>

    </ShipMethods>
    <PayMethods>

    </PayMethods>
  </Settings>
  <Products>  

<Product Id="agfasu">
  <Code>3616a</Code>
  <Description>Ageless Fashion Suit</Description>
  <Url>http://www.cl333333333d.com/agfasu.html</Url>
  <Thumb>&lt;img border=0 width=50 height=70 src=http://ep.y3333333333327706119506618_2144_317652924&gt;</Thumb>
  <Picture>&lt;img border=0 width=600 height=845 src=http://ep.yim3333333st-27706119506618_2144_317019111&gt;</Picture>

  <Orderable>YES</Orderable>
  <Taxable>YES</Taxable>
  <Pricing>
    <BasePrice>178.00</BasePrice>

  </Pricing>
  <Path>333333333333333om/wochsu.html">Womens Church Suits</ProductRef>
    <ProductRef Id="2454" Url="http://www.cl33333333454.html">Aussie Austine Spring/Summer 2011</ProductRef>

  </Path>
  <Availability>Usually ships the next business day.</Availability>
  <Caption>&lt;head&gt; &lt;meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language"&gt; &lt;style type="text/css"&gt; .style3 {  font-family: arial, helvetica;  font-size: medium;  font-weight: bold; } .style4 {  font-size: small; } &lt;/style&gt; &lt;/head&gt;  &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Wholesale Women&amp;#39;s</Caption>

  <OptionLists>
    <OptionList name="Size">
      <OptionValue>8</OptionValue>
    </OptionList>
    <OptionList name="Colors">
      <OptionValue>Red</OptionValue>
    </OptionList>

    <OptionList name="Accessories">
      <OptionValue>Suit</OptionValue>
    </OptionList>

  </OptionLists>
</Product>
```

the output i would like:

```
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA['DescriptionTag]]>  
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[CaptionTagStrippedofEscapedCharacters]]>
</description>
<link>'UrlTag'</link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:price>'BasePriceTag'</g:price>
<g:product_type>Clothing, Accessories</g:product_type>
<g:image_link>'PictureTagFrom 'src=' to '>' </g:image_link>
<g:payment_accepted>Visa</g:payment_accepted>
<g:payment_accepted>Mastercard</g:payment_accepted>
<g:payment_accepted>Discover</g:payment_accepted>
</item>
```

some of the tags dont need to be populated from the source, but are always the same, such as 'payment accepted', 'condition', and 'product type'

Comment: It would be nice if you added the original XML and what you want to accomplish, i.e., the desired result.

Comment: @Paulo: when i did that people gave the impression that the question was too general and i needed a more fundamental understanding of the problem. so i am solving the general problem with this kludge. the xml file is just: <Products><Description/><Picture/><Caption/></Products> with a few other unused tags in the product element. so what the above sheet does for me is rename the 'tags' for each element, i am then copy/paste-ing and adding the appropriate file headers. the 'picture' element has text within the tag i dont need, so i just want to have the tag around what is after src= before '>'

Comment: @bboyreason: work up a very simple example of input XML and desired output and add those to your post.  Without that nobody is going to wade through your XSLT and try to guess what you want to do.

Comment: @bboyreason: This has very little to do with both xslt and xml -- and you know the reasons. Trying to "strip-off" non-existent markup is ill-defined and the success of this depends largely on the contents of the string. As before, I recommend not even to try to do this. It is faulty and dangerous and at any moment in time your "solution" may produce very wrong results. A solution is possible, but it requires first to recover the true markup -- and this requires re-parsing. Parsing a string as XML may be possible in XSLT 3.0, but there is no known way to do  this in pure XSLT (ver. 1.0 or 2.0).

Comment: @Dimitre: i think i see what you mean, like if the string i was trying to strip with a predefined rule contained an odd amount of '>', it would come out weird. What i have now posted above is hopefully more clear, is something like this feasible to do through xslt, or should i pursue a whole other method?

Comment: How on earth did you end up with such messy XML, containing escaped markup? I would put some attention into cleaning it up to make processing easier, rather than trying to process it in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

**One shouldn't use an XML vocabulary nor an XML consumer that expects parseable data as unparsed text node**

If you do it, then you must face consequences and do proper parsing instead of some error prone RegExp or string handling.

A very **basic** XSLT parser for encode properly wellformed XHTML is found at https://bug98168.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=434081

So, you could parse your unparsed data, and then apply a second phase transformation with `node-set()` extension function.

Comment: @Alejandro: In my comment to the OP I was warning exactly about any such "solutions". Try to call the d-o-e template on this XML document and see what wrong result it produces: `<t> This is a sample text. The signs &lt; and &gt; are escaped. </t>`

Comment: @Alejandro: cool, i dont see any escaped chars in the output. now i will check out this 'node-set()'

Comment: @Dimitre: Yes, that parser only works for properly well-formed XHTML. Editing. By the way, we shouldn't encourage people with not wellformed encoded use case for DOE mechanism.

Comment: @alejandro: you mean the xml is not well formed? i was going to ask, when i use this it takes away the '<description>' tags that i put around the elements with a stylesheet. is there any way to leave these in the output? but i guess if its for xhtml probably not

Comment: @bboyreason: I mean that your **text node** must have an encoded properly wellformed XHTML fragment. Something that it's not present in neither `Caption` nor `Picture` elements from your sample.